# A question about packing relation of any given set.

Tags: fractals, geometric-measure-theory, packing-problem

Given a set $E \subset \mathbb{R}^d$, then define the $\delta-$packing of $E$ as $$\mathcal{P}(r,E)=\{ \{B_i \}_{i\geq 1} ; B_i \text{ is a ball centered on } E, \text{the radius of } B_i \text{ is } r \text{ for any } i,  \text{and for any } i \neq j, B_i \cap B_j = \emptyset  \}.$$ Then we define $N_{r}'(E)$ as the largest number of balls of radius $r$ needed for the packing of set $E$ . For simplicity, we denote $N_{R,r}'(E)$ as $\inf_{x \in E} N_{r}'(B(x,R) \cap E).$

My question is , for a given set $E \subset \mathbb{R}^d$, and for any $r_3 < r_2 <r_1$, is the following inequation 
$$N'_{r_3}({B(x,r_1)\cap E}) \geq N'_{r_2}({B(x,r_1)\cap E}) \cdot \inf_{y\in E} N'_{r_3}({B(y,r_2)\cap E})$$ true for the given $x \in E?$  More generally, is the inequation true without the choice of $x \in E$, that is, is the inequation $$N'_{r_1,r_3}( E ) \geq N'_{r_1,r_2}(E) \cdot N'_{r_2,r_3}(E)$$ true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not true in general. Consider the interval $E=[0,4]\subset\mathbb{R}$, and radii
\begin{align}
r_1&=4\\
r_2&=2(1-\epsilon)\\
r_3&=1(1-2\epsilon)
\end{align}
with $\epsilon>0$ small, say $0.01$.
Then you can check that
$$N'_{r_1,r_3}=N'_{r_3}(B(x,r_1)\cap E)=3$$
$$N'_{r_2,r_3}=N'_{r_2}(B(x,r_1)\cap E)=2$$
for every $x\in E$, and finally
$$N'_{r_2,r_3}=N'_{r_3}(B(x,r_2)\cap E)=2$$
for $x$ outside a small interval around $\{2\}$, for instance $x=4$ is ok. In particular the inequality is not satisfied.

Comment: Your answer helps me a lot! Thank you!

Comment: @HaipengChen You're welcome! Maybe you can obtain something if you require that when you compute $N'_{R,r}$ you only consider balls of radius $r$ which are entirely contained in the bigger ball of radius $R$, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Your suggestion is great. I really obtain something important when I concern about the balls of radius $r$ which are entirely contained in the bigger ball. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: @HaipengChen Sorry what's the inequality you're looking for?

Comment: If I change the definition of $N'_{r}(B(x,R) \cap E)$ as the largest number of balls of radius $r$ inside the ball $B(x,R)$ and centered on $B(x,R) \cap E$, is this inequality $$\cdot  N_{r}(B(x,R) \cap E) \geq  N'_{r}(B(x,R) \cap E \geq N_{2r}(B(x,R) \cap E)  ) $$ holds for any $2r < R$? The notation $N_{r}(B(x,R) \cap E)$ represents the smallest number of balls of radius $r$ needed to cover $B(x,R) \cap E$.

Comment: The inequality is looking for the relationship between 2 kinds of balls, one is the largest numbers of balls centered and entirely inside the set of radius $r$, another is the smallest number of balls needed to cover the same set of radius $2r$.

Comment: I am very sorry for my previous typing errors.